# Mute local notification sound when is app already running

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa

I am working on an alarm application. When the app is in the background a local notification informs the user that an alarm is ringing and playing a sound. But when the app is already in foreground I do not want the notification sound to play, but a custom sound. I cannot find how to mute the notification sound and as a result both sounds play simultaneously. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I restarted my device and the problem solved. It probably is an iOS bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your app is open and running in the foreground, the default behavior is that the sound is not played and the user doesn't receive any alert/banner from the OS. You can receive the notification through the following method (in the class that is your AppDelegate):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Do something");
}
```

And from there you can trigger any other method.

From the [documentation on UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If the application is foremost and visible when the system delivers
>   the notification, no alert is shown, no icon is badged, and no sound
>   is played. However, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is
>   called if the application delegate implements it. The
>   UILocalNotification instance is passed into this method, and the
>   delegate can check its properties or access any custom data from the
>   userInfo dictionary.

Comment: I don't know what I changed but now my notification sound plays when the notification fires. I do not want to cancel the notification. I just want to stop it from playing the sound

Comment: Yes. It didn't used to. But now it does it. I cannot find how to handle it.

Comment: Check the edit I just made. This is very strange that you are receiving the notification sound...